# Regex Convert string formula into mysql like query in php

Tags: php, mysql, regex

What is the best way to convert this string formula into MySQL like search query in PHP.

### Example Input

```
(Business Intelligence) AND ((Business Objects Specialist) OR Cognos Impromptu OR (Crystal Reports) OR (Datawarehousing) OR (PowerBI) OR (SSAS) OR (SSIS) OR (SSRS))
```

### Expected output:

```sql
(column LIKE '%Business Intelligence%') AND ((column LIKE '%Business Objects Specialist%') OR (column LIKE '%Crystal Reports%') OR (column LIKE '%Datawarehousing%'))
```

### Other possible inputs:

- dotNET AND PHP
- (Functioneel-Applicatie-Beheer) OR (Technisch-Applicatiebeheer)
- (msSQL-dba) OR (Oracle)
- (Delphi)
- dotNET AND (episerver OR sitecore OR sitefinity OR umbraco)
- (dotNET AND (dotNET OR .Net core OR ASP.Net OR Azure OR C# OR Entity Framework OR episerver OR sitecore OR sitefinity OR umbraco OR vb.net OR Xamarin))
- dotNET AND ( HTML5 OR Javascript )

Comment: What happened to "Cognos Impromptu"?

Answer (score -1):

Instead, I suggest you aim for REGEXP (instead of LIKE):

```
(Business Intelligence) AND
 ((Business Objects Specialist) OR Cognos Impromptu OR (Crystal Reports)
  OR (Datawarehousing) OR (PowerBI) OR (SSAS) OR (SSIS) OR (SSRS))
```

-->

```
    col REGEXP "(Business Intelligence)"
AND col REGEXP "(Business Objects Specialist)|Cognos Impromptu|(Crystal Reports)|(Datawarehousing)|(PowerBI)|(SSAS)|(SSIS)|(SSRS)"
```

Part of that was trivial -- "\s+OR\s+" --> "|".  No, even that is not trivial because you could have a phrase that has " OR " in it.

Let's back up a bit...  If you are forcing the user to enter the original string (with AND, OR, and parens), then why not force them to learn REGEXP syntax; it's not much different?

If you really want to do the parsing, I recommend you take a beginning Computer Science class in lexical scanning and parsing.  Some issues you will need to handle:

- Multiple spaces instead of one.
- Parens being optinoal.
- Capitalization -- probably handled by `COLLATION`.
- Understanding when to do or not do the AND/OR in code, not in the regexp.
- The parens around strings are not important, but the other parens provide precedence info.
- Etc.